# Have more than one Worksheet_Change in a Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking to limit my workbook users to 1000 characters over a range of cells **`(Example: A5:A30)`**.

In other words limit the total characters in the range **`A5:A30`** to 1000 characters.

When a user fills in a cell that sends the range over the 1000 character limit, it will call Application.undo which should just remove the last text that they added.

However since I have another **`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Targe As Range)`** on the worksheet, it causes a bug.

Below is both Worksheet_Change subs. Both use the same cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim charCount As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6,E11,E16")) Is Nothing Then

        Dim arrValues As Variant
        arrValues = Range("E6,E11,E16").Value2

        Dim i As Long
        Dim tempSplit As Variant
        Dim j As Long

            For i = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
             tempSplit = Split(arrValues(i, 1), " ")

            For j = LBound(tempSplit) To UBound(tempSplit)
                charCount = charCount + Len(tempSplit(j))
            Next j
        Next i

    End If

If charCount > 1000 Then
   Application.Undo
    MsgBox "Adding this exceeds the 1000 character limit"
 End If


            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
        'assumes the comment cell is one column to the right
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = "**"
        End If

    End If

            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
        'assumes the comment cell is one column to the right
            Target.Offset(-1, 1) = "**"
        End If

        End If

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
           Target.Offset(-2, 1) = "**"
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way around this so I can have two **`Worksheet_Change`** on the same worksheet?

Comment: we could probably just put the code together into the same `worksheet_change` if you paste both of the code sets

Comment: What do you want to do with the second Worksheet_Change?

Comment: @RicardoA the second, is to place a character inside a specific cell depending on the choice of a drop down on the same worksheet.

Comment: could you move this comment over to the question that the code came from? it doesn't quite belong here

Comment: is the value of one of those cells maybe being changed by another macro? because in that case i believe it will have cleared the undo cache and will throw an error because it cannot undo

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Those same cells are the ones affected by the second Worksheet_Change. When a certain word is selected from the drop down, 
** will display in the cells.

Comment: Then if you want specific help I can't really debug it until I know what you're working with

Comment: Since you want to to do a change when you select something from a Dropdown, make the dropdown an ActiveX dropdown. (on the Developers menu you can select 2 dropdowns, select the ActiveX), then you can code the event for the dropdown inside the "sheetname" object with: Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()

Comment: I have looked into that option when I was first making the dropdowns. I use both but for this case ActiveX is not favourable

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is an *event handler* procedure. It handles the `Change` event of the `Worksheet` interface, and it's only going to work if it has that exact specific name, including the underscore (and a given procedure name can only exist once in a module). If you "need two handlers", what you want is to write two distinct `Sub` procedures, and make your handler conditionally branch into (/invoke) either - use @Vitaya's `Select Case` statement, or use an `If...Else If...End If` block, whatever. Just don't make a 10K-liner event handler and you'll do great.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two `Worksheeet_Change` events in one sheet. But, one is quite enough:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case True
    Case Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A5:A30")) Is Nothing
        DoThingOne
    Case Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("B5:B30")) Is Nothing
        DoThingTwo
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub DoThingOne()
    Debug.Print "THING ONE"
End Sub

Private Sub DoThingTwo()
    Debug.Print "THING TWO"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this answer would be more valuable with `DoThingOne` and `DoThingTwo` in place of `Debug.Print` statements, and `Private Sub DoThingOne` and `Private Sub DoThingTwo` underneath - already upvoted though

Answer (score 0):

How about this revision using Vityata's idea?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case True

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6,E11,E16")) Is Nothing

            Dim charCount As Long

            Dim arrValues As Variant
            arrValues = Range("E6,E11,E16").Value2

            Dim i As Long
            Dim tempSplit As Variant
            Dim j As Long

            For i = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
                tempSplit = Split(arrValues(i, 1), " ")

                For j = LBound(tempSplit) To UBound(tempSplit)
                    charCount = charCount + Len(tempSplit(j))
                Next j
            Next i

            If charCount > 1000 Then
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .Undo
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With

                MsgBox "Adding this exceeds the 1000 character limit"
            End If

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6")) Is Nothing

            If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
                'assumes the comment cell is one column to the right
                Target.Offset(0, 1) = "**"
            End If

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing

            If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
                'assumes the comment cell is one column to the right
                Target.Offset(-1, 1) = "**"
            End If

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8")) Is Nothing

            If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
                Target.Offset(-2, 1) = "**"
            End If

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Code line "For i = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)" displays Run-time error 13 "Type mismatch" when I use the drop down or type then click out of the cell.

Comment: @Tmacjoshua maybe i can cheat the system here if we surround that `For i ..... Next i` with `If isArray(arrValues) Then  ... (for i) ... End If`

Comment: Ok so the error does not happen, and the drop down places the ** in the cell but the limit of 1000 characters does not seem to be working.

Comment: @Tmacjoshua i'm not sure, this is getting to just conceptualize :/